# npm how to sync global packages between different computers

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I installed some npm global packages in my work computer, and I want to sync these packages with another computer.

Normally in a project we have `package.json` to record package information, and we just need to `npm i` to install all the packages, but seems there's no `package.json` for global environment.

**Update:**

Thanks for everyone's help, [npm-modules-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-modules-sync) is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below command to get the list of all the installed npm packages.

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

and the result should be something like this.

```
 /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.4/lib
 ├── express-generator@4.14.0
 ├── gulp@3.9.1
 ├── learnnode@1.0.0
 ├── mocca@1.0.3
 ├── mocha@3.2.0
 ├── nodemon@1.10.2
 ├── npm@2.15.1
 ├── react-native-cli@1.0.0
 └── rnpm@1.9.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, get the package list is really very helpful. If I could get a `package.json` file it could be more interesting.

Comment: If my answer is helpful please use the up arrow to vote it. thanks :)  @LarryChen

Comment: I voted yesterday, since my reputation is less than 15 so it won't display here, sorry about that. But seems that vote has been recorded.

Comment: This shows a list of all installed packages. Even those which were not installed manually (`npm i -g {some package}`).

Answer (score 1):

try this, It will list all the packages without the dependencies.
npm list -g --depth=0

If you want to list the dependencies you can do

npm list -g

Comment: Thanks for your additional anwser, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without using any additional NPM modules.

Run the following command on the first computer which has the global packages installed:

```
npm list -g --depth=0 > global_npm.txt && sed -i '' 's/├── //g' global_npm.txt && sed -i '' 's/└── //g' global_npm.txt && sed -i '' 's/\/usr\/local\/lib//g' global_npm.txt && sed -i '' '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' global_npm.txt && rm global_npm.sh; touch global_npm.sh && cat global_npm.txt | while read line; do echo "npm install -g "${line} >> global_npm.sh; done && chmod 755 global_npm.sh && rm global_npm.txt
```

This will give you a file global_npm.sh which contains all the installed global packages in a format that's ready to be installed.

Copy global_npm.sh to the second computer and run the following command:

```
./global_npm.sh
```

**That's it.**

Explanation of the command:

```
npm list -g --depth=0 > global_npm.txt
```

List all the installed global packages and write the output to temporary text file

```
&& sed -i '' 's/├── //g' global_npm.txt
```

Remove unwanted characters

```
&& sed -i '' 's/└── //g' global_npm.txt
```

Remove unwanted characters

```
&& sed -i '' 's/\/usr\/local\/lib//g' global_npm.txt
```

Remove unwanted line

```
&& sed -i '' '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' global_npm.txt
```

Remove empty lines

```
&& rm global_npm.sh; touch global_npm.sh
```

Remove the global_npm.sh file if exists and write an empty one

```
&& cat global_npm.txt | while read line; do echo "npm install -g "${line} >> global_npm.sh; done
```

Insert "npm install -g " before each line

```
&& chmod 755 global_npm.sh
```

Change the file chmod so it's executable

```
&& rm global_npm.txt
```

Remove the temporary text file